# Beautiful soup parsing full html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following `type`:

```
<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
```

How would I print all of the html that is contained in this tag? I want the output to be the string:

```
<div class="txt-block">
<h4 class="inline">Country:</h4>
<a href="/country/us?ref_=tt_dt_dt" itemprop="url">USA</a>
</div>
```

Doing `.text` gives me:

```
Country:USA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing unicode on this worked for the above circumstance:

```
item = unicode(item)
```